# entity framework inserting a many-to-many relationship between two existing objects while updating

Tags: entity-framework, insert, many-to-many

I'm trying to do this:

```
using(var context = new SampleEntities())
{
     User user = select a user from database;

     //Update user's properties
     user.Username = ...
     user.Website = ...

     //Add a role
     Role role = select a role from  database  
     //trying to insert into table UserRoles which has columns (UserID, RoleID)  
     user.Roles.Add(role); 

     //Apply property changes
     context.ApplyPropertyChanges("Users", user);
     context.SaveChanges();
}
```

However, I get an exception telling me that "The existing object in the ObjectContext is in the Added state" and can't "ApplyPropertyChanges". 
If "ApplyPropertyChanges()" is removed, it adds a User.

What orders should these methods be called? I don't need to do them separately right?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look to me like your User object is detached, so you shouldn't need to call `ApplyPropertyChanges()`.

Comment: @redbluegreen If you find an answer to your question, please post it so that others can benefit.